# Eclipse don't want create R.java in new project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I'm using Eclipse juno and i have installed all plugs in.
Everything was working fine, but this morning when i opened my project there wasn't R.java.
I tried to create new project but in New project R.java was missing also.
I tried everything(clean project,change to "wrap content"), but nothing.
There are no errors because this is new project where single line of code isn't written, there is just some default code.

Comment: Are u creating Android Application Project in eclipse...?

Answer (score 1):

Hey so this is a bug with eclipse refer to the thread for more deatils but basically: do not wrap any of your content but instead check your imports for import android.R
this has been covered here already on SO [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)
basically the problem is

*Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask Eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.*

Comment: I read and tried all this before asking question, nothing worked. I will just try re-instaliling everything. Eclipse generate BuildConfig.java but not R.java

Comment: I would give it another look through before resorting to this, but if your sure you have done that, I'm not to sure what the problem could be myself

Comment: https://www.box.com/s/nymhxxga6emavv197vb6

Here is screenshoot. I don't want reistalling all, so if you could find what is wrong.

Comment: can you blow out the imports so i can actually see them on you MainActivity.java ... from what it looks like this is indeed your problem

Comment: here there are   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

Comment: add an import com.example.hoceli.R    and then rebuild your project it should fix it

Comment: isn't working
these are all errors
 https://www.box.com/s/o1q5a76qs76g96elndry

Comment: Okay ... in your manifest `<activity  android:name=".MainActivity"` not com.example.hoceli.MainActivity

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: hmm I'm not to sure then sorry ... I edited your question to include your screen shots maybe someone else can help you out